# Url format in a json query string

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, query-string

In [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) it says:

> Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query
>   string

What is the format of this string? I see a url of this format coming from such a jquery json call from client side:

`http://<domain:port/path/something.html?somevalue=a;othervalues=1,2,3,4;v=3`

Is this format specific to json? I generally thought that the parameters appended to the URL are separated by `&`

Comment: Show your code. It should be an ordinary query string with parameters separated by `&`, so you may be doing something to get in the way.

Comment: @Barmar:Its not my code. I see it coming and I happen to know that the client uses `jquery`. But I am not so experience in front end to give you better details

Comment: It doesn't matter whose code it is, show it. They're probably not giving an object as the `data:` parameter. Either they're constructing the URL by themselves with the query string, or they're doing `data: string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the format of this string?

The property can be given a value of either an object or a string.

If it is given an object, then its keys and values will be formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (just like a form submission).

If it is given a string, it will be whatever that string is — so it can be "Whatever the author of the code using it wants it to be".

> I see a url of this format…

That would be a case of "Whatever the author wants". Note that `;` and `&` can be used interchangeably in a number of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` decoding libraries. This is [recommended by the HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2).

> Is this format specific to json?

No. There is no connection between the data format of the URL used to make a request and the data format of the response.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the format of this string?

If you used the `data: {...}` format then it will be sent as [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) format which is:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2...
```

Example:

```
$.getJSON('http://<domain:port/path/something.html', { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, function(result) {

});
```

> I see a url of this format coming from such a jquery json call from client side:
>   `http://<domain:port/path/something.html?somevalue=a;othervalues=1,2,3,4;v=3`

This is query is not sent using the data parameter but probably directly hardcoded in the url (first parameter of the getJSON method):

```
$.getJSON('http://<domain:port/path/something.html?somevalue=a;othervalues=1,2,3,4;v=3', function(result) {

});
```

Or they provided the data as string and not as key/value pair:

```
$.getJSON('http://<domain:port/path/something.html', 'somevalue=a;othervalues=1,2,3,4;v=3', function(result) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Supporting ";" as separator in query-strings is a W3C reccomendation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#ampersands-in-uris